# Codeigniter all URLs go to default controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I'm testing my php app built with Codeigniter on local host (wamp). In Firefox all my URLs go to my default controller unless I add a trailing slash.

e.g. `site.com/controller/method/`

Even methods not expecting a third URI segment are redirected. Does anyone know the reason behind this?

**Update**

application/config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pages"; //loads homepage view
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

I'm not using .htaccess on localserver

Comment: Try with another server (e.g. on some other system, like if you use windows now, let's say linux). Does your test give a different result?

Comment: How does your .htaccess and application/config/routes.php look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned you are not using .htaccess but without rewriting `/controller/method/` into appropriate path your application will fail. Usual .htaccess file for a CodeIgniter application should contain at least the following configuration for rewriting

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your URL like this. This is default URL.

site.com/index.php/controller/method/

If you are configured .htaccess

site.com/controller/method/ this url is correct